# Converting a gmail email to kindle as readable document

Tags: conversion, kindle-paperwhite

I have a kindle paperwhite. I have html formatted email I'd like to read on my kindle.
I tried several steps, but every time I try, I end with a document with pictures in it. Like pdf. Output is not formattable. The text has fixed size, I can pan or zoom over the pages.

I'd like to have same output as, for example, I send a page to the kindle via Send to Kindle extension.

- I've sent the email to my kindle mail. The result was no text, just images bundled to the original email
- I've downloaded the email as html, converted through calibre to azw3 format. The result was,that all document was converted to pictures. As if it was pdf.
- I've opened the html with word and resaved it to docx. Conversion through calibre to azw3 or mobi resulted to same pdf-like output.
- If I convert the email to text. I will get formattable result, in sense, that I can now change size of the font on kindle and whole document is formatted to the kindle page size, but I loose all original document formatting, pictures, titles, lists and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use a PDF via *Send to Kindle Email Address* using the steps below in order to retain the functions you are asking for- variable size font, annotations, etc.

1. Open the Gmail email you want to transfer and click the print button
   at the top right corner.
2. From the print screen, change the printer option to PDF and save.
3. You must have a Kindle
4. Send the PDF as an attachment to your Kindle Paperwhite via your Send to Kindle Email Address BUT you must put **convert** in the subject line. This automatically converts the PDF to Kindle format retaining the features mentioned above.

Just as a heads up, Amazon may limit how many documents you send and store through the Kindle Personal Document Service, so I would routinely delete old documents and make sure you have backups on your computer of any personal document you might want at a later date, just in case Amazon deletes them for any reason.

There is also a Kindle Convert app you can download from [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00K7HEGZ6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K7HEGZ6)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can solve the problem:

1. Open [Gmail in HTML view](https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html&zy=h) and select the email you want to send to kindle.
2. Use [Send to Kindle](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-to-kindle-for-google/cgdjpilhipecahhcilnafpblkieebhea?hl=en) extension to send the page to your kindle.

Let me know if it works